# Who was the first female dwarf identified by name in the Hobbit/LOTR saga?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit

While the fathers of several "son of" dwarves are named in the epic, I can't recall that a female dwarf was ever referenced by name. Who was the first female dwarf identified by name in the Hobbit/LOTR saga? Is there even one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any female characters in the Hobbit?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36621/are-there-any-female-characters-in-the-hobbit)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[Dís](http://www.tolkiengateway.net/wiki/D%C3%ADs), who is Fili and Kili's mother and Thorin's sister, gets a brief mention in the appendices to *Lord of the Rings*. [According to Wikia](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Dis), she is the only female dwarf Tolkien ever names.

Comment: Just to be clear - she is mentioned in The Hobbit, but isn't named there.

Comment: New phone. Who Dís?